# Como usar JavaScript JSON para recuperar resultado em C?

Tags: javascript, ajax, c, json

Apreendi que o JSON serve para fazer a comunicação entre sistemas. Sendo assim é possível me comunicar com o C, recuperando variáveis através de um JSON gerado pelo código e mandar através do response AJAX do JavaScript?

Ou existe uma técnica mais conhecida de fazer a comunicação entre os sistemas, JavaScript [web] e C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON é um formato de dados. Uma das coisas em que ele é usado é a comunicação entre o cliente e o servidor *web*.

Cada lado não precisa saber a tecnologia que está do outro lado, por isto existem padrões regulando a comunicação. De fato o servidor não precisa saber se ele está servindo um navegador web, uma aplicação móvel, um software desktop ou mesmo um outro servidor. Muito menos precisa saber que tecnologia está fazendo a requisição, desde que ela siga os padrões estabelecidos.

O mesmo vale no sentido contrário. Essencialmente qualquer linguagem de programação pode ser usada para fornecer resultados para os requisitantes desde que siga estes padrões. E boa parte do padrão pode ser atendido através de um servidor web como o Apache ou IIS, portanto a sua aplicação C só precisa saber entregar o resultado para este servidor.

Os dados requisitados pelo JavaScript em um navegador ou não podem ser entregues dentro de qualquer formato, desde que o *script* requisitante saiba o que fazer com ele. Evidentemente que não é comum e não costuma valer a pena criar formatos próprios.

Inicialmente o formato proposto para usar em requisições assíncronas era o XML. Daí o X do nome [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). Mas o formato foi considerado pesado e complicado e foi quase universalmente substituído pelo JSON, mais leve e simples.

A não ser que você tenha um bom motivo para escolher outro formato ou outra forma de comunicação, é melhor seguir esta consagrada mesmo.

Então se sua aplicação C que vai atender as requisições recebidas pelo servidor HTTP é capaz de formatar os dados em JSON, faça isto e estará bem servido. Se ela não é capaz e não consegue resolver isto, terá que escolher um formato e adaptar o JS para entender este formato.

Se você estiver fazendo algo que será consumido por terceiros é melhor usar algo bem padrão, mesmo que tenha uma dificuldade a mais, ou até uma camada a mais.

Alguns poderão achar que um formato binário pode trafegar menos dados. Isto pode ser verdade em algumas situações. Mas é possível fazer compressão dos dados texto e reduzir o tráfego. Dependendo da quantidade de dados pode não compensar. Adotar um [formato binário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) tem complicadores e apesar de viável, não é comum ser adotado.

Não faça em C algo diferente do que você faria em outra linguagem a não ser que tenha algum requisito que exija uma mudança.

Comment: +1 Para referência do AP, formatos usados com esse propósito são comumente chamados **formato de troca de dados** ([*data exchange format*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_exchange#Data_exchange_languages)), ou às vezes formato de intercâmbio / *interchange* (mas não confundir com [o formato `.dif`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format)).

Comment: Concordo com isto mas apesar da definição usualmente aceita (na página oficial e WIkipedia, por exemplo) ainda ser o formato de troca de dados, hoje ele é usado para mais que isto.

Comment: desculpa a demora pra comentar, eu não entendi exatamente se é possível utilizar ou não o JSON para recuperar resultados do C. Qual a melhor forma de ser feito? Porque me falaram que vários sistemas web grandes usam C++ como camada mais baixa, mas não vi nada na internet falando sobre isso.

Comment: Sim, é. A melhor forma é algo um tanto vago, não é possível responder isto. É raro C ou mesmo C++ ser usado para isto. O objetivo delas é atender outro tipo de aplicação. Fazer em C é essencialmente igual a fazer em qualquer linguagem, só que você vai ter que gerenciar a memória, terá que criar um monte de coisa própria para lidar melhor com isto, provavelmente terá que escolher um biblioteca adequada para o que precisa já que não tem nada padronizado.

Comment: Talvez esta blibioteca ajude um pouco.: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk